# Full-text boolean search for stop-word returns null result

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Ive searched through a ton of questions on fulltext searching and I can't find a solution to this problem.

My command is the following:

`SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE MATCH (c1,c2,c3) AGAINST (:keyStr IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

If :keyStr == '+apple*' I get values returned.

If :keyStr == '+this*' I get nothing returned.

if :keyStr == '+apple* +this*' i get nothing returned.

If :keyStr == '+apple* +chicken*' I get values returned.

'this', 'apple' and 'chicken' are all in the db and all three queries should return non-null results.

I think when there is a stopword entered the database automatically returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that 'this' is a stopword AND the inclusion of + and * around 'this'.

The reason is that `:keyStr == '+apple* +this*'` requires both apple* and this*. But since the only thing that matches 'this*' is a stopword, you are seeing not results.

You could try `:keyStr == '+apple* this*'` or insert a record with 'thisorthat

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely. [Boolean Full-Text Search Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) clearly states that it won't be considered as a stopword:

> If a word is specified with the truncation operator, it is not stripped from a boolean query, even if it is too short (as determined from the ft_min_word_len setting) or a stopword. This occurs because the word is not seen as too short or a stopword, but as a prefix that must be present in the document in the form of a word that begins with the prefix.

Comment: lol how can I show its actually happening?
I removed the '*' from all words and now:
'+apple +this' returns values but '+this' returns null

Comment: @JoseCalderon Did you change anything in the configuration?

Comment: nope.  I think when :keyStr = '+this',  mysql ignores '+this' and does a full-text search for an empty string, which returns null.

Comment: @JoseCalderon It's exactly what the example says: "Then a search for '+word +the*' will likely return fewer rows than a search for '+word +the'"

Comment: So do you believe what I said in my original post now? This is basic stuff(I'm a noob), how could there not be an article written somewhere about how to handle this.

Comment: @JoseCalderon What words do you have that start with `this` and don't return a result? Can you provide a simple example?